# having problems getting the correct size of data(struct)

Tags: c#, performance, unsafe, value-type

I am testing `struct` vs `class` vs `Tuple<int,char[]>`
in both managed vs `unsafe` parallel and normal execution
so to get the size of data handled in each case i have issues getting the correct size of `valueType`

```
public struct Schar
{
    public int V;
    public char[] ChrArr;
}
Schar tSchr = new Schar()//set value: V=1,ChrArr= 'a','b','c','d','e'...
```

now when I set `tSchr`, no matter size of `ChrArr`, I get same results
(8 @`I386` and 16 @`AMD64`)

I have tried `sizeOf` /`Marshal`

```
    unsafe int GetDataSizeOf(System.ValueType TestedSchar)//could be any Structure not specifically 'Schar'
    {
        int rt=Marshal.SizeOf(TestedSchar);
            //return sizeof(TestedSchar);
    }
```

I could have add a `Length` parameter to `GetDataSizeOf` and multiply but it will be OK only if I pass `Schar` type of `struct` and not any other.
if another struct will have 2 `char[]` fields or other variation of other forms it would not be OK to count the length and so...

How is the correct way to implement a size of in unmanaged ?

### update

this next struct is `blittbale`
which does get the correct size when I have tested it via `GetDataSizeOf()`

```
public unsafe struct chars32A
{
    public int V1;
    public int V2;
}
```

what if i make another one made of the above struct as follows,

```
public unsafe struct chars32
{
    public chars32A Fld1;
    public chars32A Fld2;
}
```

do i have to check each field within the struct for its size too ?

Comment: @Rakhitha Not sure why you've deleted your answer, which is correct.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin i didn't see it..(:

Comment: The explanation is: all arrays are reference types, so they're allocated on the heap, not as part of the struct. The struct only allocates space for a pointer to the array, which is the same size no matter how big the array actually is.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin meaning i should check size of object rather `valueType` ?

Comment: I don't think you're following what I said. The memory for the array is allocated separately, somewhere on one of the heaps. It isn't part of the memory allocated for the `Schar` type, and in fact having it that way wouldn't be possible since all instances of a value type occupy some fixed amount of memory, whereas a `char[]` can be as large or small as you please. The behavior you're seeing is as expected.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin, i have 'dissassembled' it then checked each field(`int` and `char[]`) of `Schar` struct and sum of both is the right size i think .. that's not a solution i presume..